# What's the purpose of the Zener diodes in this boost circuit?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, boost

I am looking at this [boost converter](https://www.instructables.com/Charge-Electric-Bike-Battery-with-Solar-Panel/) for stepping up voltage to charge a Li-ion battery:

[image]

It looks like a standard boost topology, but I am new to this and am wondering: What is the purpose of the Zener diodes D4 and D5 (specified to be 1N5363BG in the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials))?

Comment: The body diode is correct.  When you put a positive \$V_{DS}\$ on an N-channel FET, it shouldn't conduct.  The diode direction is consistent with that.

Comment: Ah you're right I was confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1N5363 is a 30 volt Zener diode. Two in series make a 60 volt Zener diode and, together, they limit the supply voltage on the INA169 high-side current monitor to 60 volts (the maximum value for this chip). I don't think they will be very effective but, maybe the designer did.

Comment: Thanks that helps but why do you think it's intended to protect the INA169 as opposed to the load? Or do you think it's protect both? Why do you think they wouldn't be effective?

Comment: We don't know what the load is. It won't be effective because zener tolerances can push the highest voltage to be over 60 volts and, the limit for the chip is 60 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka Absolute max Vin for the INA169 is 75V, recommended max is 60V.

Comment: Yes I know that.

Comment: @Andyaka Sure, but others reading may not.  It implies that the designer was protecting against absolute max instead of recommended max and not that they were ignoring tolerancing.  I'm not making a value judgment either way, but it helps us to understand what the designer was thinking.  Just adding info.

Comment: We cannot understand what the designer was thinking. Anyone thinking of using that chip is always encouraged to read the data sheet from front to back - this is a "given" in EE circles.

Answer (score 5):

It's always difficult to read the mind of the circuit designer, but it appears that D4 and D5 are there as a last-ditch safety against overvoltage in case the controller gets confused.

Depending on their relative current handling capabilities, R5 *may* also serve as a last-ditch fuse: it's not uncommon in power applications to design a resistor to burn up or melt off the board as sort of an unofficial fuse.

Comment: Thanks, just to check: two Zeners in series (in the same direction) multiplies the breakdown voltage by 2 right? Since the breakdown of each Zener here is 30 V, the new breakdown is 60V? Seems high for charging a battery with max voltage of 43V but I guess it's a last ditch as you say.

Comment: Zener diodes aren't perfect regulators.  30V Zeners would have been chosen to not leak appreciable current at the design voltage.  If you want to assign yourself some homework, find a 22V Zener diode datasheet and look at the current vs. voltage curve around 22V.